# Pointer to console arguments

Tags: c

As a C newbie, I have trouble to understand the following:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     char **inputs = argv + 1;
```

char **inputs is a pointer to char *argv[] which is also a pointer, right? But why I have to add the "+1" at the end? Will this be an extra space for the '\0' character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

argv[0], or the first argument, is the string holding the name of your program.

Comment: ... so the first actual argument is argv[1].

Answer (score 3):

argv[0] is the program you're currently running 
argv[1+] are the arguments passed to the program 
Perhaps not the best reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html

Answer (score 1):

This is just to ignore the first entry which holds the path name that invoked the program. There is always at least one argument passed to main and this is it. Try passing some arguments yourself and print them..you'll get a better idea :)

Answer (score 1):

To explain the "+1" in this context, we are doing pointer arithmetic. This is saying that you want the next memory address after whatever `argv` points to. Since `argv` points to the first address in an array of strings (`char*` in C), then the next memory address is guaranteed to be the second element in the sequence (arrays are laid out contiguously in memory). Thus, `argv + 1` is equivalent to saying `&argv[1]`.

As stated before, the first element in `argv` is just the program name. So you want everything after that for program inputs